# What is いやほい from the Kyary Pamyu Pamyu song 原宿いやほい HARAJUKU IYAHOI?

Tags: song-lyrics, music

What does いやほい mean in this context?  Or is it nonsense or onomatopeia?  I'm not finding a conclusive result in the dictionary.

Results I get are, for instance:

いや which could be disagreeable, increasingly, no, head house, birthplace, originator

ほい which could be linen kariginu, supplement, heave-ho, yes, one's real intent

So... "no-yes"...?  "linen kariginu originator"...?  ...?

Comment: Though I never saw this particular written form, I am very sure that it is a variant of やっほい.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most native speakers haven't heard いやほい before this song. When [an announcer asked the lyricist about this word on Nov/11/2015](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9E%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AE%E3%81%84%E3%82%84%E3%81%BB%E3%81%84%22&src=typd), he said something along the lines of "The meaning is not known and each person has their own way of interpreting it". So it's basically his made-up word which just sounded nice to him.

Still, I feel this is meant to sound like a symbolic 掛け声, something like "Yo Ho" (of pirates) or "Heigh-Ho" (of dwarfs in Snow White). Some people seem to believe this had been actually used among young people around Harajuku, but I could not find a definitive evidence for that.

Answer (score 6):

Isn't it just a 'call'? Like "yahooo!" or "hey hey!" ... at least, that's the sense with which I take sounds like that one. Basically that would mean they're saying "hi" to Harajuku in an uber-genki way. I know that やっほー！ is such a sound, and this seems fairly close to that, with extra "cuteness" added in.

Answer (score 0):

It is roughly equivalent to the English word "Yahoo!" when shouted in happiness. An example would be when riding a bucking bronco, and you are waving your hat, and shouting yahoo!.

During the MV for this song, you can clearly see a Japanese equivalent being presented to the viewer.